# Is 25G 250iops is necessary for journalling in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, journaling

I followed an [offical document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/welcome.html) to deploy mongodb to AWS,After the template completed,I found two huge volumes are allocated :
[image]

After some investigation,I found it hard coded in template file(provided by the guide):
[image]

And used for journaling:

[image]

I am not a dedicated database administrator ,so I want to know what is reason to allocate so huge storage

I want to know if decrease the rate for iops for journalling volume will decrease the overall database performance

Comment: Unless you actually know that your workload needs that kind of IOPS, I wouldnt use it, its actually rather expensive.

Comment: @datasage I do not know what is the significance of journal and log in mongodb, if it is irrelevant,I will just reduce the resource for it

Comment: Every operation done in Mongo is written to the journal, this is used for replication to other instances in a cluster. You can configure the log to be as detailed as you want it to be. Obviously the more detail you are logging, the more IOPS you will use.

Comment: Is 25GB necessary ? someone mention the size should be fix and it seems 3GB is the fixed value

Comment: Also,is the journalling performance related to external performance ?

Comment: It depends on the size of your data and workload. There is not a good once size fits all solution. If you are asking these questions, you may not be in a place where you need separate volumes for journals and logs.

Comment: Journaling has to do with replication and crash recovery. But with enough write volume, you can run into IO constraints.